# Stop animation Canvas pod in Swift

Tags: swift, canvas, view

So I have installed Canvas pods to animate quick and easy. I have added some animations, but the animations play instantly when the view is presented. How can I stop that initial animation so it will only play when the AnimationTest.startCanvasAnimation() is called?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At first, I set type as empty.

And when it is needed, set code:

```
AnimationTest.type = "shake"
```

E.g.

```
@IBAction func Pressed(sender: AnyObject) {
AnimationTest.type = "shake"
AnimationTest.startCanvasAnimation()}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's explained in the CSAnimationView.h

```
    @property (nonatomic) BOOL pauseAnimationOnAwake;  // If set, animation wont starts on awakeFromNib
```

So, you have to insert on more key in the User Defined Runtime Attribute under Indentity Inspector. You will have this:
type, duration, delay and the last one is pauseAnimationOnAwake with is Boolean and set to true.

Thats it!